# Updating multiple areas with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've started learning ajax and javascript recently, and still getting a handle on it. But I have a simple goal I'm trying to achieve, and I'm half way there.

For example. I am working on the ability to manage bookmarks saved by one user to be used by other members. I have the code built where I can add, edit, and delete the item live on the page. But how I learned how to do the edit part is a 'click the field area' to start the edit, then 'click out of the field area', to finish the update. I'd really like to change that to a way to click a button to submit the edit.

Also on the page it has a "View Bookmark" button right next to the delete option, but I am not sure how to update that link when I update the text area of it without refreshing the page.

So essentially I want to learn a more efficient way to do live updates via ajax, and then when the update is completed, update all the instances of that same item on the page (which is only two areas).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can post my original code but I think I might be better to learn from someone who knows better. lol

Comment: Well, all these updates must be done manually. If your objects are repeated, you can group them by (css class, attr name, html object) and then via jQuery selectors can iterate. [https://api.jquery.com/each/](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: To post your original code is good idea so the people here can see what you tried and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic question so I will answer generic answer.

If you have, for example, 2 `div`s

```
<div id="area1"></div>
<div id="area2"></div>
```

And you want to call the server and get 2 data's for each `div`, So it will looks like this: (I'm using `jQuery` for the example..

```
$.ajax({
   url:'server_url',
   method: 'post',
   success: function(data) {
      $('#area1').html(data.objForArea1);
      $('#area2').html(data.objForArea2);
   }
});
```

The `JSON` that return from the server (for example)

```
{
   objForArea1: '<div class="list-item">item 1</div>...'
   objForArea2: '<div class="list-item">item 1</div>...'
}
```

So you read the response from the object that return from the `ajax` call, then you put the data wherever you want.